# make a increaseKey for list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, adt

assuming a list `A` with strings, and an offset `x`.

`A=["a","b","c"]`
`x is int`
`len(A) is int`

I need to serialize and return json `J` such that for each
`n<len(A)`
`J[x+n]=a[n]`

I currently use dict assigning, but It feels like their is something more **efficient**
instead of going over the entire list.

answer needs to be `O(1)` or a contradiction.

Thanks.

```
dict={}

for i,x in enumerate(List):
    dict[i+offset]=x
```

Comment: Can you show us your code with the dict assigning?

Comment: @eumiro it's simple traversal. nothing intresting

Comment: Your variable naming could do with some lessons; don't shadow builtins (like with `dict = {}`), and read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the standard variable naming stuff and lots more useful stuff.

Comment: **answer needs to be O(1)** - I am afraid this won't be possible. Dictionary building is at least O(n).

Comment: "Answer needs to be O(1)" is an unreasonable request. I haven't paid much attention to the actual question at present, but it doesn't sound like it'd be possible.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan its for displaying , my naming is not like that

Comment: @shevski: good, but get into a habit of using useful names in your questions, too.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I need a Structure that implements `increaseKey` in O(1).

Comment: @shevski What does O(1) gain for you when the serialisation is still O(n)? An O(n) `increaseKey` doesn't change the overall complexity.

Comment: @Duncan, right. but still if there is a way to do so i'm sure someone will need it. for another problem

Comment: At least in CPython, the relative time complexities of these operations can be found at http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to construct a `dict` from your list, you can use a hack that depends on implementation details of the `json` module:

```
class OffsetDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, lst, offset):
        self.lst = lst
        self.offset = offset
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return bool(self.lst)
    def iteritems(self):
        return enumerate(self.lst, self.offset)

A = ["a", "b", "c"]
d = OffsetDict(A, 5)
print json.dumps(d)
```

The above code prints

```
{"5": "a", "6": "b", "7": "c"}
```

Because constructing an `OffsetDict` instance does not iterate the list, this part would be O(1).  Creating the JSON output inevitably remains O(n) of course.

The code relies on the fact that `json` treats every subclass of `dict` as a `dict` and only calls the `__nonzero__()` and `iteritems()` methods.  Don't expect that code to be very robust.  A more robust version would need to reimplement all of `dict`'s methods.

In Python 3.x, overwrite `items()` instead of `iteritems()`.

Comment: didn't know I can wrap `dict`

Comment: @shevski: Please understand that the only reason the above class derives from `dict` is to trick the `json` module into treating instances of this class as `dict`'s.  It isn't really a "wrapped `dict`".

Answer (score 1):

Given following variables (don't use dict/list as variable names!):

```
offset = 5
A = ["a","b","c"]
```

Your example code can be written as:

```
d = dict(zip(range(offset, offset+len(A)), A))
```

or using `import itertools as it`:

```
d = dict(it.izip(it.count(offset), A))
```

or (Python 2.6 and newer):

```
d = dict(enumerate(A, offset))
```

In all cases `d` is now `{5: 'a', 6: 'b', 7: 'c'}`. Comparing the speeds, the first is the slowest and there is no significant difference between the latter two.

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` constructor can take an iterable of key-value pairs to construct the dict. So, you can have:

```
some_dictionary = dict((i + offset, x) for i, x in enumerate(some_list))
```

In newer Pythons (2.7 or 3.x), there's special syntax for dict comprehension:

```
some_dictionary = {i + offset: x for i, x in enumerate(some_list)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not prepend a list of length `offset` to A?

```
result = [None] * offset + A
```

Comment: it will take O(offset) to insert that

Comment: And creating a dict from a list is at least O(len(A)). The only way you can have O(1) is by modifying your JSON client to get items at index (x - offset) :-)